# How is scope handled for my DOM event handler?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, scope

Up until now I thought I had a good grasp of variable scope and when closures are required. However this extremely simple example has me puzzled.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDfC3/)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doit() {
            var text = 'Clicked (1)';
            document.getElementById('clickable').onclick = function(evt) {
                this.innerHTML = text;
            };
            text = 'Clicked (2)';
        }
    </script>
    <title>page</title>
</head>
<body onload="doit()">
    <h6 id="clickable">Click me</h6>
</body>
```

The handler function is executed when the element is clicked with the element as its context. I know that a closure isn't being implicitly created as my update to `text` is recognised in the handler function. To my knowledge `text`'s scope is limited to the `doit` function.

How is `text` still in scope when the handler function is executed?

Comment: Scope is carried down, when you reference a variable in a higher scope, you create a closure.

Comment: @elclanrs if this is a closure shouldn't it keep the value of `text` as 'Clicked (1)'?

Comment: The assignment occurs when the event is triggered, by that time `text` is already `Clicked (2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closure is created that contains the `doit()` variables like `text` and it's a closure that exists beyond the lifetime of the `doit()` function.  That closure allows the event handler to have access to the `text` variable even though the `doit()` function has finished executing.

In this particular case, it's pretty simple.  A function defined inline within another function has access to all the variables of the parent and if the internal function is some sort of event handler that can be called later, that creates a lasting closure so those variables remain available to the internal function even after the outer function has technically finished executing.  That's a closure.

I like to think of closures in terms of the garbage collector (just because it helps me understand it better).  The basic concept of javascript garbage collection is that a variable exists and is preserved as long as some callable code still has a reference to that variable and could potentially refer to it.  In the case of a callback functions that can be called sometime later (either event handlers or things like ajax completion callbacks), these functions can still be called at some later time so any variables that are initially in scope to them and potentially used by them will be kept by the garbage collector because there are still live references to them thus they aren't relevant to garbage collection.  That is the case with your `text` variable.  It will be kept by the garbage collector as long as the onclick event handler function is still alive.

A closure keeps the actual variable and any subsequent changes to that variable are live and affect future references to that variable - that's why it will have the value of `'Clicked (2)'` when the event handler is clicked.  It doesn't make a copy of the variable.  However, if `doit()` was called again, that would create a new set of local variables for `doit()` and thus a new closure and new event handler and new copy of the `text` variable.

Each time the event handler runs, it uses the then current value of `text`.